# Benefit of (logically/virtually) separate I/O and memory bus

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, computer-architecture

In my course on embedded systems, it is explained that memory inputs can be separated from I/O inputs using a "mode bit" for the address decoder. The most obvious advantage of this is that the amount of address lines need to be decoded can be reduced if you have a separate addressing system for your memory and your I/O. Are there any additional benefits? Does having these logically separated have other benefits such as being able to use different clock speeds or transfer logic?

Comment: Relevant question from stackoverflow with a long answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215878/what-are-in-out-instructions-in-x86-used-for

Answer (score 2):

My interpretation of what you are describing is to simply sub-divide the address space into two halves - one half for IO and one half for memory.  You're not creating two separate busses there, but only one that is used for two logically different tasks.

While that can make decoding of the address bus simpler, it doesn't improve performance at all.

Many embedded microcontrollers use an architecture known as Modified Harvard Architecture.  In this you do have a number of different physical busses, each with its own purpose - one for RAM, one for ROM, maybe one for IO.  These have the big advantage that it is possible to access different things *at the same time* which you can't with a single sub-divided bus.  It does make programming more complex though.

Comment: I believe he's asking about the I/O and memory busses in x86 processors. They are actually different address spaces and have separate instructions for access.

Comment: But still only a single physical bus. No real difference than just nominating the most significant address bit as a memory / IO differentiator.

Comment: They may use the same lines, but the IO bus is 16 bits and the memory bus is 20, so the combined address space isn't contiguous or evenly sized. Also the instructions are non-interchangeable, so the separation is enforced by the design of the CPU. Perhaps it would've made more sense to use that pin as a 21st address bit, but that's history.

Comment: @Austin Also he says "In my course on embedded systems" so it's more likely to be 8051 not x86. Yes, they do live in the past on these courses.

Comment: I'm actually just asking in general from a theoretical standpoint. Not actually studying any particular computer system.

Answer (score 1):

This is what the X86 architecture does with IN/OUT instructions, which address peripherals rather than memory.

Different transfer logic can be useful. For example, not caching access to peripherals. Or having different behavior for unaligned reads. It also gives you a "free" 17th bit in a 16-bit architecture, which is when the technique was introduced. The clock speed must remain the same, but potentially you can have a different number of "wait states".

However, these days it's considered better to just make the MMU smarter and allow it to handle these effects.

Comment: Or, to use different words for the same thing: The I/O clock can be a different speed than the memory clock. The processor clock "must remain the same".

Answer (score 0):

According to my instructor, there are many potential benefits, because designing the buses in this way allows for totally different setup parameters. This means you can have different data/address widths, as well as different clock speeds.